# MySQL per-user table or common?

Tags: mysql

I need to make a library of products (this can be large), should I make a table per-user (`lib_$user_id$`) or a common one (`libs`)? Which is better in term of versatility and performance? Thanks.

Comment: dynamic number of tables is always poor idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different table for each user is not good idea it would increase table as per user.

Use unique table for libs

---

where **UserId** will be `Forigen key`